# Отправить udp запрос через Socks5 proxy средствами php

Tags: php, proxy, udp

Мне нужно отправить udp запросы и получить ответ, используя Socks5 прокси с авторизацией на php.
Нигде не могу найти рабочий вариант, находил только отправку http запроса.